# Dynamically loaded Google Map API in Javascript: Click on marker popup

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

So I've got a map I'm working on loaded dynamically like this:

```
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>                                

    var marker<?php echo $count; ?> = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng<?php the_field('longlat'); ?>, map: map, title:"<?php the_title(); ?>, <?php the_field('address'); ?>", icon:image });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker<?php echo $count; ?>, 'click', function()
    {

        alert('you clicked: <?php the_title(); ?> - <?php the_field('address'); ?>');

    });

    <?php $count++ ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

What I want it to do is elegantly load the marker popup with the title and address... being these two values from php:

```
<?php the_title(); ?> - <?php the_field('address'); ?>
```

Currently it does this but in an alert...

So  how do I set this up so it appears in a popup above the marker?

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest you check out the `infoWindow` class and related documentation at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow

There are also related code samples at:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery

Where you have the alert code you can put something like:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
infowindow.setContent('Whatever you want in the popup');
infowindow.open(map, this);
```